# I can't install .net framework 4 on my desktop which has Windows XP service pack 2 O.S

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, windows-xp-sp2

I made a small simple c# application in Visual studio 2010 ultimate and i deployed it and it requires .Net framework 4 to run but when I tried to run this app in a desktop of Windows XP Service Pack 2 it is showing me an error that it requires "Windows Imaging Component" and it is providing me a link to download it - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=162643&clcid=0x409

but when i download WIC from this site and tried to run on that desktop it is showing me an error that ??????????????????????Windows XP????????????   nw what should i do to run my app in that desktop plz suggest me some thing.

Answer (score 1):

Why SP2 for XP? Are you running XP x64? If you aren't using x64 make sure you have windows installer 3.1 and it should install with no issues. As a side note however, .net 4.0 is NOT supported on XP SP2.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_programs/windows-imaging-component-32bit-on-xp-sp2-refuses/5fe4bd9a-1634-464f-bc8e-e04c1e758ad4) can help.

Windows XP SP 2 is very old and you may need to upgrade to SP3